# Problems while finding the distance between two points

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int y1;
    int y2;
    printf("Enter the value of x1 and y1 %d %d ",x1,y1);
    scanf("%d %d",&x1,&y1);
    printf("Enter the value of x2 and y2 %d %d ",x2,y2);
    scanf("%d %d",&x2,&y2);
    int l1=x2-x1;
    int l2=y2-y1;
    int len1=l1*l1;
    int len2=l2*l2;
    int length=len1+len2;
    int lengthf=sqrt(length);
    printf("The length between the points = %d",lengthf);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I was not expecting the locations of the variables. I have to get the distance between two points.

Comment: `sqrt` returns a `double`, are you sure you want to truncate it to an `int`?

Comment: Aside: missing `#include <math.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

**There are several faults in the code:**

0. `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2` are used uninitialized that invokes UB.
1. You are losing precision to the actual result by casting a `double` to an `int`.
2. You are missing `math.h` library.
3. You don't check for the `scanf()` values.
4. Lots of redundant variables.

---

The code can be rather written this way. Follow the comments to understand.

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1

// Storing the coordinate values in a structure.
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct point p1 = { 0, 0 };
    struct point p2 = { 0, 0 };

    fprintf(stdout, "Enter the value of x1 and y1: ");

    // Validation of input -- considered good practices.
    if (fscanf(stdin, "%d %d", &p1.x, &p1.y) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: The value(s) are invalid.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Enter the value of x2 and y2: ");

    // Validation of input -- considered good practices.
    if (fscanf(stdin, "%d %d", &p2.x, &p2.y) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: The value(s) are invalid.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Finally, evaluation of the distance using pow() and sqrt().
    double distance = sqrt(pow(p2.x - p1.x, 2) + pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2));

    fprintf(stdout, "Distance between two points: %.2lf\n", distance);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```